# how can i position right absolute if the page is larger in width than my screen?

Tags: html, css, positioning

i want to position an element on the very right of the page.

i tried this on firefox 8, but its wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="min-width:2000px;background-color:#222">
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;right:0;width:200px;background-color:#eee">this should be on the right, even if you scroll right</div>
<div style="width:100%">this is just to adjust the page to max width</div>
</body>
</html>
```

that will position it on the right of the visible part of my screen, but my page is wider, so if i scroll to the right, the div a is not on the right anymore, but has a space to the right, that is the space that was not visible on pageload

I want to have it positioned **really right** of the **page content** (not of the **visible part**)
so if i don't scroll right, then it should be outside of the visible area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="min-width:2000px;background-color:#222; position: absolute;">
<div id="a" style="position:absolute; right: 0; width:200px; background-color:#eee">this should be on the right, even if you scroll right</div>
<div style="width:100%; ">this is just to adjust the page to max width</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Setting absolute on body should fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/JXgk9/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify `position: relative;` to your body style.

**Edit**: This is a very good reference site for learning css positioning: [Learn CSS Positioning in 10 Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: doesn't `position: relative` on `<body style>` solved your problem? you have to understand `position: absolute` in some situation have to pair with the parent's position setting in order to get desire result.

Answer (score 1):

Change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`, and it will remain fixed to that location, regardless of scrolling in any direction.

#### Update

Sorry, my bad - didn't quite understand your question.
If you want it to be positioned all the way to the right of the body, [you only need to add `position: relative;` to your `<body>` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/JhhXZ/), and the behavior will be that which you're after.

You need to add this property, because otherwise, an absolutely- (or relatively-) positioned element will be positioned relative to the nearest parent element with a non-`static` position applied to it.

Comment: no, that would only work, if you would want to have it always visible

Comment: Ah, my bad - misunderstood your question; I updated my answer to reflect that.